# Superfluous scrolling in CIDER REPL when showing result

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

How can CIDER REPL be configured so that it only scrolls when that's necessary to show a result?

By default, CIDER REPL (0.18.0) always scrolls the point to the bottom of a window when showing a result, even when there's enough space for it.

[image: REPL-demo]

I find this jarring. I'm forced to type at the bottom of the window just to prevent "jumps." Ideally, no scrolling should occur in this example. (The point should only scroll to the bottom when a result is longer than the space below the point.)

Comment: Btw, I've updated the manual to mention this http://www.cider.mx/en/latest/using_the_repl/#auto-scrolling-the-repl-on-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is controlled by the customization variable `cider-repl-scroll-on-output`:

```
(defcustom cider-repl-scroll-on-output t
  "Controls whether the REPL buffer auto-scrolls on new output.

When set to t (the default), if the REPL buffer contains more lines than the
size of the window, the buffer is automatically re-centered upon completion
of evaluating an expression, so that the bottom line of output is on the
bottom line of the window.

If this is set to nil, no re-centering takes place."
  :type 'boolean
  :group 'cider-repl
  :package-version '(cider . "0.11.0"))
```

Try changing its value from the default `t` to `nil`.

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go with this.